# How to Print a BST in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Just started learning about binary search trees.  Below is the code I wrote for constructing one. I think it's correct.  I tried to write a function, CreateBST, that will construct the BST after passing it a list of elements.  The code runs but I'm not sure how to tell if it actually works.  Could someone please assist me with either writing a function to print the tree or check the code itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self, nodes = None):
        self.root = None

    def createBST(self, nodes):
        # Pass all elements of binary search tree to nodes variable
        if nodes is not None:
            node = TreeNode(val = nodes.pop(0))
            self.root = node
            print(nodes)
        def rootDown(self, nodes):
            node = self.root
            for elem in nodes:
                if elem < node.value:
                    node.left_child = TreeNode(val = nodes.pop(elem))
                    node = node.left_child
                    return(self.rootDown(node, nodes))
                if elem > self.root.value:
                    self.right_child = TreeNode(val = nodes.pop(elem))
                    node = node.right_child
                    return(self.rootDown(node, nodes))

BST([90,100,75,50,20])
```

Building a BST in python

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `TreeNode` class, you have `self.right_right` instead of `self.right_child` Fix this typo in `__init__`
Also I have noticed the last line of your code, you are creating an instance of the `BST` class but not calling the `createBST` function to actually construct that binary search tree. You need to call the `createBST` func

instead of using `pop` try using `remove` to remove an element by its value from the list.
For printing you can iterate over elements and print them:

```
    def printBST(self):
        self._printBSTUtil(self.root, 0)

    def _printBSTUtil(self, node, level):
        if node is None:
            return

        self._printBSTUtil(node.right_child, level + 1)

        print('    ' * level, node.value)

        self._printBSTUtil(node.left_child, level + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- The `TreeNode` constructor defines `right_right`, but that should be `right_child`
- The `BST` constructor gets a `nodes` argument, but doesn't do anything with it. It should probably call `createBST`
- The `createBST` method never calls `rootDown`, so it only adds one node.
- `rootDown` is defined with a `self` parameter that -- when looking at the recursive calls -- should be a `TreeNode` instance. But it also makes access to `self.root`, indicating that `self` would be the BST instance. This is a contradiction and cannot work.
- `rootDown` always adds a node at a place (either `left_child` or `right_child`) without checking whether there is already a node there! It should follow the path until it reaches a leaf and only then create & attach the node.
- In `rootDown`, `nodes.pop(elem)` is not doing what you intend. `pop()` takes an *index* as argument, but *elem* is a node *value*. Just pass `elem`. I would not call `pop()` at all, because it is not nice to the caller that we should delete elements from their list. The iteration over the `nodes` list is all we need.
- In `rootDown`, `if elem > self.root.value` is not the right condition. You should compare with `node.value` here.
- In `rootDown`, `self.right_child` is not the attribute to assign to. It should be `node.right_child`
- In `rootDown` you have a `return` inside the loop that will interrupt the loop, and performs a recursive call. It is confusing that you both have a loop *and* recursion. You should choose between the two.

Here is a correction of the code, trying to keep close to what you had:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None  #  typo fixed

class BST:
    def __init__(self, nodes = None):
        self.root = None
        # add this
        self.createBST(nodes)

    def createBST(self, nodes):
        if nodes is not None:
            node = TreeNode(val = nodes[0])  # don't pop -- not nice for caller
            self.root = node
            for elem in nodes[1:]:
                node = self.root 
                while True:
                    if elem < node.value:
                        if not node.left_child: # first check we are at leaf!
                            print("adding node at left of ", node.value)
                            node.left_child = TreeNode(val = elem) # elem is the value!
                            break
                        node = node.left_child
                    if elem > node.value: # don't compare with root
                        if not node.right_child: # here too
                            # not self!
                            node.right_child = TreeNode(val = elem) # here too
                            break
                        node = node.right_child
```